# Find the % change in sales with previous month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a table which contains the region with highest percentage change in sales for each accounting month.

```
Accounting_Month   Region  Sales
Jan'19             North   100
                   West     50
                   East     20
                   South    10
 Feb'19            North   200
                   West     80
                   East     10
                   South    12
 Mar'19            North   220
                   West     70
                   East    200
                   South    10
```

The sample output is as follows:

```
Accouting_Month   Highest chnage
  Feb'19             North
  Mar'19             East
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have df:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='Accounting_Month', columns='Region', values='Sales')
df_change = df_pivot.pct_change().fillna(0)
df_change['Highest_Change'] = df_change.idxmax(axis=1)
final_df = df_change[['Highest_Change']].reset_index()
```

Note that it will take based on percentage not base don absolute number